# Sql Server - proper syntax for rolling back a transaction

Tags: sql-server

The below sql gives a syntax error at `RAISEERROR`, which goes away if I remove `[Tran1]` from the query. What is the correct syntax to rollback an aliased transaction and then call `RAISERROR`?

```
 BEGIN TRY
 BEGIN TRANSACTION [Tran1]
   ...sql goes here... 
 END TRY
 BEGIN CATCH
   ROLLBACK TRANSACTION [Tran1]
   RAISEERROR ('Error occured')
 END CATCH;
```

Also, if I remove the `[Tran1]`I get:

> Cannot roll back RAISEERROR. No transaction or savepoint of that name
>   was found.

Comment: Maybe all you need is add semicolon, like this: `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION [Tran1];`

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? 2008?

Answer (score 0):

You do not mention the essential COMMIT TRANSACTION [Tran1] within the 'TRY' block. I presume you have that.

The RAISERROR will raise an error by itself, since it has to be coded like

`RAISERROR('Error Occurred',0,0)`.

A RAISERROR statement with an error will call the BEGIN CATCH section, but there is no transaction anymore to ROLLBACK.

Answer (score 0):

It's better if you don't lose information about the original exception. In **SQL Server 2012 and above** there is a `THROW` clause exactly for this purpose. So you can simply do:

```
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION [Tran1];
    --- Some SQL here --
    COMMIT TRANSACTION [Tra1];
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION [Tran1];

    THROW;
END CATCH;
```

In **SQL Server 2008R2 and below**, it's a bit more cumbersome to preserve the error information:

```
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION [Tran1];
    --- Some SQL here --
    COMMIT TRANSACTION [Tra1];
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION [Tran1];

    -- Now throw the exception
    DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000);
    DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT;
    DECLARE @ErrorState INT;
    SELECT @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
        @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
        @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();
    RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState);
END CATCH;
```